# What is The highest number of information bits $N_b$ and the smallest number of bits?

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory, entropy

I want to find the highest number of information bits $N_b$ that can be reliably transmitted over a binary symmetric channel (BSC) with fixed channel parameters, error probability $ \sigma$ = range from $ 0-0.5$, and channel uses $N_c = 100$ bits.

The next question is to find the smallest number of bits $N_b$ that is required for representing $N_s $ source symbols $s$ for the source distribution and k-bit quantizer.

Is the highest number of information bits related to the entropy of the source symbols? and What are the formulas to calculate these quantities?

Comment: If the error probability of the BSC is $0.5$ it means the output is independent of the input and so  no information can be delivered. The highest number of bits that can be reliably delivered is 0.

Comment: A binary symmetric channel with an error rate of $\ 50\%\ $ has zero capacity, so it's not possible to transmit *any* information over it. The channel output is a completely random sequence of bits, independent of its input, so it cannot give you any information about what that input was.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: what if I consider the error probability to be in the range from 0-0.5 and I want to plot a graph. what is the formula for the highest number of information bits $N_b$?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "reliably". Often, in information theory, the term "reliably" means that the deciding error probability vanishes as the number of channel uses tends to infinity. However, here you are asking for a finite number of channel uses and thus need to concretize reliably.